# How do I convert a String to runnable code? (in Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, compilation

I'm making a little game in unity and right now I'm trying to build the quest system.
This game is going to be a simulation, so there's a huge amount of different data classes / systems the quests are going to have to interact with. 
I *can* just make a bunch of utility classes... or even make a fake "database" to handle data calls... but that's inelegant.

Surely there's gotta be a way where I can just denote actual code from a string?

Example:

```
String questText = Hello player.getFullName();, how are you?

questResults<String>[1] = player.inventory.add(GameObjectBuilder.Create(new WhateverObject()));
```

I am using Unity's `ScriptableObject` to make quests, so that I can fill in text data via the editor rather than do it on IDE side (especially since unity doesn't support interpolated & composite strings as far as I know).

I know Java has an API called "Reflection" which from what I understand does something like this, but I was never able to fully wrap my head around it.

So how do I convert elements from a string into runnable code?

If that is possible, will that cause preformance issues with an indefinate amount of objects that might be encountering scripts that need to be converted?

Are there any other alternative methods that achieve a similar goal? (this one is just a curiosity)

Comment: have you tried [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2), its development is faster than reflection.

Comment: @LeiYang I'm not even fully sure if Reflection is the technology I need in this case, I probably should have just not mentioned it. 
Does CSharpCodeProvider allow me to turn C# detected within a string into an actual runtime process?
If so, does it function with unity?

Comment: it works in C#. please read the doc first and do some experiments.

Comment: Ok so just to make sure I'm understanding how CSharpCodeProvider works... is this how the process would play out: GameEngine[ detects code ] -> GameParsingEngine [ writes code into a source file ] -> CSharpCodeProvider [ Compiles and runs the code within the game ] ?

Comment: i think you even don't need write the string to source file. it compiles in memory at runtime and the IL can be run.

Comment: Oh right I could just put the String into a DOM without actually writing anything... Ok im going to go play around with this for a bit and see if it's what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative method, you can use a keyword that you search for  and replace, rather than write the actual code directly into your string. I would suggest using this approach as it's cleaner to read and easier to maintain. I have used this approach in a similar system.

It works well if there is only a small number of possibilities that you will need to resolve (or you don't mind adding 'handlers' for all keywords., you can include a sort of keyword in your text, that you can pass through a method before using it.

For example..

`Hello {PLAYER_NAME}, how are you?` - this is the raw string.

```cs
public string ParseQuestText(string input)
{
    if(input.contains("{PLAYER_NAME}")
        input.Replace("{PLAYER_NAME}",player.getFullName());

    /Add other replacers here

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about the keyword route at the initial stages. I'm designing around future SQL implementation so this can work as a multiplayer thing... but that lead to realizing I'd want processing commands, not just data requests. That lead to me spending a day writing my own scripting language which made me realize the class-granularity that would occur if i tried to go this route. 

The game is a rather in depth data-based business simulation (as opposed to physics) so there's going to be a huge amount of different classes which would then need utility methods like yours.

Comment: Or `string.format ("Hello {0}, how are you?", player.GetFullName());` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I should clarify. `string questText` is a field I set within the unity editor, not progromatically. I also didn't want to confuse the qustion further but _in_ the quest it would actually read `Hello, $player.getFullName();, how are you today?` the `$` denotes the beginning of code inserted into display-text, the `;` naturally ends it. I have a pretty straightforward design for actually parsing the commands, it's the ability to dynamically generate a throwaway class for the infinite custom statements that will be needed, rather then a million utility classes.

Comment: Realistically, how many unique methods will you need? Doing this via a string.Replace would be much easier than what it sounds like you want to do, not to mention a lot safer (which I would be concerned about if you ever make this content 'moddable').